# left join in laravel return null if data exist in database

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to left join two tables in laravel. after joining got all second table value is empty but data exist in a database .

Comment: Can you share the table structures?

Comment: sorry, bro, i am new for a stack . so I don't know how to share table structures

Comment: You can paste the CREATE codes of the tables here?

Comment: I pasted bro check it

Comment: What about the other table? BTW you duplicated your join statement.

Comment: i added another one table

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this:

```
$contacts = DB::table('C_Contacts')
        ->leftJoin('C_Contact_Category_Map', 'C_Contacts.contact_id', '=', 'C_Contact_Category_Map.contact_id')
        ->get();
```

Comment: i got same result bro

Comment: Then check your database because it might really be empty or you are joining the wrong table, or you might not be saving the contact_id's on the category map table etc.

Answer (score 0):

Can You try this

```
$contacts = DB::table('C_Contacts')
    ->join('C_Contact_Category_Map', 'C_Contacts.contact_id', '=', 'C_Contact_Category_Map.contact_id')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Please check comment - i just replace leftjoin to join